# How to launch .jar files?

Tags: 13.10, java, minecraft

I am trying to launch Minecraft.jar and I cannot make it boot as an executable. I have gone into the properties and set it to executable, and I have installed jdk-7u55-nb-8-linux-x64.sh with and without superuser. I do run a x64 computer. I recieved the file from the website [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7-netbeans-download-432126.html). I have tried `./Minecraft.jar` and `java -jar Minecraft.jar`

Output of `java -jar Minecraft.jar`

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Output of `./Minecraft.jar`

```
./Minecraft.jar: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found
./Minecraft.jar: line 2: $'\b\b\222t\354B\002': command not found
./Minecraft.jar: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
K-*��ϳR0�3���M���u�I,.�R�K-����KM.JL+�K��/).)J,�s��x�x�PK'K-.
```

[image: Output]

Comment: What do you get when you type `./Minecraft.jar` and `java -jar Minecraft.jar`?

Comment: The output of `java -jar Minecraft.jar` indicates you have not installed java, install it using the answer given [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download java or jdk 6 in software center.
When downloaded right click on minecraft.jar ang go to its settings and allow it to launch as a program

Comment: The funny thing is that I installed Java straight from Oracle and I couldn't get it to work, but this did for some reason. Thanks!